# one laravel folder with many database based on link

Tags: php, laravel

7 project 
lets say im working with locahost 
i want if the url is 
http://localhost/project1
then the database will be 
project1
and if the link is 
http://localhost/project2
the database will be project2
ect 
any help here thanks a lot 
i tried to do this 
inside database.php

```
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = explode('/',$url);
    $url = $url[1];



    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => $url,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' =>'secrit',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

its working if i only enter the main path of laravel project 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel you can set the database connection dynamically with:

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
    "host" => "...",
    "database" => "...",
    "username" => "...",
    "password" => "..."
]);
```

So of you have a Route where the first part is your project you could set the database connection in your Controller. Otherwise you could try to use Events to set the database connection with a Kernel-Event.